# How to let Google Compute Engine continue running after the terminal is closed?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I access the google compute engine through terminal, roughly looks like

```
gcloud compute ssh instance-name --zone zone-name
```

everything is fine, I get the a terminal, then I start a long-lasting program through that terminal on that instance.

But the problem is, once I closed the terminal, the program also stopped.

How could I start the program from the terminal and keep it running after having closed the terminal.

Comment: screen, nohup. this is a question for [unix.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which instance you are using, but in Debian/Linux you can use [screen](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/34/Using_GNU_Screen) for this.

Answer (score 0):

[`tmux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) is another option, similar to `screen` which was mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31140391/3618671).